# Spring Batch limit running jobs

Tags: java, spring-batch, jobs

Has "spring batch" ability to limit run jobs without manual check job status? Job can be different or instances of one job. Need something like configurable property.

Comment: I think there's no way to do it, since each running job will be a different thread. In fact, if you want to run different instances of the same job, you must provide different executions parameters, because Spring batch will not run two instances of the same job with the same parameters at the same time, it will throw `JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The only way is to manually check via [`JobExplorer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/explore/JobExplorer.html) interface or directly query [jobs metadata tables](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html)